# How to adapt the design of my website for all the resolution of the screen in ie7 to more?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, autoresize

I'm designing a website that suits the screen size but should work in ie7 to more,How can I adapt the website to user's screen resolution no matter what screen resolution the user have in ie7? thanks.

--edit--

this site is my reference http://www.rei1440project.com/#

Comment: Seems to me that someone made a mistake in agreeing to create a responsive website when the minimum browser requirement is IE7. Your best bet would be to drop one or other of those requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [css3-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/), which attempts to provide media query support (a key component of responsive web design) to legacy browsers.

EDIT: Check [this](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids) out for fluid grids and [this](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images) for fluid images. Both seem to include Internet Explorer accessibility.